What is SiLabs equivalent of Arduino's analogRead()?
I need to get the output of a DHT11 temperature sensor for a club project but unfortunately we are only given SiLabs BGM220 Explorer Kit instead of a Arduino board.
The SiLabs Documentation is no help at all. I need a way to get the voltage (or better, temperature) that the DHT11 returned.
I tried using
GPIO_PinOutGet(gpioPortB, 0); //PB00.
I expected it to return the voltage but it seems that's not the function use.

Arduino is pretty much the only platform where the users get everything spoon fed (or else they might risk learning something). Writing a driver for an on-chip ADC is usually pretty easy, as drivers go. Check if there's app notes or examples though.

Are you using the Arduino IDE?

It does have an arduino core available https://github.com/SiliconLabs/arduino so you can try that

Note that GPIO_PinOutGet isn't related to a pin's input at all, whether analog or digital. It tells you what the current DOUT is for a pin.

@IanAbbott Im using Simplicity Studio

@KIIV I'd prefer to use Simplicity Studio for this as I'd written a big chunk of my project in Simplicity Studio and I don't want to rewrite all of it again.

Perhaps you could use the Arduino library for the DHT11 as a guide to help you implement it. But note that Arduino libraries are C++.

Why do you need an analog read at all? Looking at the DHT11 datasheet, it communicates via a single-pin digital interface. As a side note, sticking with Simplicity Studio is good, but you do need to read the datasheet and have a look at the reference manual for the device you're using, and check the documentation for the SDK.

I second Thomas' comment. You should read the datasheets befor you even think about writing any code. You're asking for directions without knowing the destination. that's never a good idea. also you should abstract your problem. you should ask how to do an analog to digital conversion (ADC), not how to do the equivalent of Arduino's analogRead. Using the right keywords will greatly increase the number of search results and you'll probably get along without another question. although you actually need 1-wire you should definitely learn how to do ADC with any MCU you're using.
